# Why can’t I convert to polar for $\int_0^1 e^{-x^2}dx$

Tags: calculus, polar-coordinates, jacobian

I tried to apply the common technique for the Gaussian integral but I changed a bound:
\begin{align}
I &= \int_0^1 e^{-x^2}dx \\[2mm]
I^2 &= \left( \int_0^1 e^{-x^2}dx\right) \cdot \left( \int_0^1 e^{-y^2}dy \right) \\[2mm]
&= \int_0^1\int_0^1 e^{-(x^2+y^2}dxdy \\[2mm]
\textrm{Changing to polar:}& \, x^2 + y^2 = r^2 \, ,\, \,\textrm{and} \,\, \, , dydx=dA = rdrd\theta \\[2mm]
 e^{-r^2} \,\textrm{ has circular symmetry}& \textrm{meaning that I can integrate it from} \, 0 \to 2\pi \\[2mm]
&= \int_0^{2\pi}d\theta\int_0^1 re^{-r^2}dr \\[2mm]
&= \pi\left(1-\frac{1}{e} \right) \\[2mm]
I &= \sqrt{\pi-\frac{\pi}{e}}
\end{align}
Which turns out to be wrong. Where did I go wrong. thanks

Comment: your limits of integration are wrong. As a double integral, you're integrating over a square in the first (top-right) quadrant so the angle shouldn't even go up to $2\pi$. Also, the region is a square, not a circle, so polar coordinates are not a good idea at all; you'll get a very ugly expression for r as a function of $\theta$

Comment: @peek-a-boo Oh, how do I find them?

Comment: Your original limits of integration are a rectangle, you can't do polar.

Comment: Your polar limits define the unit circle, but your cartesian limits define the unit square.

Comment: The reason why polar coordinates are effective for the usual Gaussian integral is that $[0,\infty)^2$ has a nice representation in polar coordinates. By contrast, $[0,1]^2$ isn't nice in polar coordinates and so it's not productive.

Comment: If $0\le \theta\le \pi/4$, then $0\le r\le 1/\cos\theta$. 

If $\pi/4 \le \theta\le \pi/2$, then $0\le r\le 1/\sin\theta$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'll focus on three issues: why your reasoning was wrong, what a corrected version of your idea obtains, and why you'll still need a numerical method at some point.

The region $0\le x\le1,\,0\le y\le1$ is not equivalent to $0\le\theta\le2\pi,\,0\le r\le1$. It's actually equivalent to $0\le r\le\sqrt{2},\,\theta_\min(r)\le\theta\le\tfrac12\pi-\theta_\min(r)$ with $\theta_\min(r):=\arccos\min\{1,\,\tfrac1r\}$. So$$\begin{align}I^2&=\int_0^1re^{-r^2}dr\int_0^{\pi/2}d\theta+\int_1^2re^{-r^2}dr\int_{\arccos\tfrac1r}^{\pi/2-\arccos\tfrac1r}d\\&=\tfrac12\pi\int_1^2re^{-r^2}+\int_1^2re^{-r^2}(\tfrac12\pi-2\arccos\tfrac1r)dr\\&=\tfrac12\pi\int_0^2re^{-r^2}+2\int_1^2re^{-r^2}\arccos\tfrac1rdr\\&=\tfrac14\pi(1-e^{-2})+2\int_1^2re^{-r^2}\arccos\tfrac1rdr.\end{align}$$The last integral is the challenge! One way or another, we need numerical methods, as per e.g. @DMcMor or @Turing's answer.

Answer (score 2):

The error is in the line:

> $e^{-r^2}$ has circular symmetry, meaning that I can integrate it from $0$ to $2\pi$

Using the same (incorrect) argument, you would get
$$
1=\int_0^1\int_0^1 1 dxdy=
\int_0^{2\pi}d\theta \int_0^1rdr=\pi
$$

In general, you have
$$
\iint_{\color{red}{x^2+y^2\le 1}}f(x^2+y^2)dxdy=\int_0^{2\pi}d\theta\left(\int_0^1f(r)rdr\right)
$$
but
$$
\iint_{\color{red}{[0,1]\times[0,1]}}f(x^2+y^2)dxdy\ne\int_0^{2\pi}d\theta\left(\int_0^1f(r)rdr\right)
$$

Answer (score 2):

Accounting for the shape of the domain, and using symmetry

$$\int_0^1\int_0^1e^{-(x^2+y^2)}dx\,dy=2\int_0^{\pi/4}\int_0^{1/\cos\theta}re^{-r^2}dr\,d\theta=\int_0^{\pi/4}\left(1-e^{-1/\cos^2\theta}\right)d\theta$$ and you are stuck.

Comment: Enough! My old friend 

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use polar coordinates, for your integration range is a rectangle, as @Joshua Wang told you in a comment.

In this situation, a good way to attack the problem is to consider that, since you're bounded between $0$ and $1$, you can use Taylor series:

$$\int_0^1 \sum_{k = 0}^{+\infty} \frac{(-x^2)^k}{k!}\ \text{d}x = \sum_{k = 0}^{+\infty} \frac{(-1)^k}{k!} \int_0^1 x^{2k}\ \text{d}x = \sum_{k = 0}^{+\infty} \frac{(-1)^k}{k!} \frac{1}{2 k+1}$$

Now this series is well known in literature, and you get:

$$\sum_{k = 0}^{+\infty} \frac{(-1)^k}{k!} \frac{1}{2 k+1} = \frac{1}{2} \sqrt{\pi } \text{erf}(1)$$

Where $\text{erf}(\cdot)$ denotes the Error Function (special function): https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Error_function

($\text{erf}(1) \approx 0.842701(...)$)

Comment: Probably better than this is to recognize $\int_0^1 e^{-x^2}\;dx$ is (up to a change of variables) the definition of $\text{erf}$.  No need to convert to a series, then look up the series to find it is $\text{erf}$.

Comment: It should be noted that the last expression follows from the definition of the error function: $$\operatorname{erf}(x):=\frac{2}{\sqrt{\pi}} \int_0^x e^{-t^2}\,dt.$$

Comment: @GEdgar You're surely right, but I thought that in this way he could have had the whole series in front of his eyes, and maybe he would have had a bit of fun in taking the very few terms to have a numerical approximation and play a bit :D

Comment: @Semiclassical Super right indeed (read the comment above, I "justified" my answer) :)

Answer (score 0):

Just to provide another straightforward solution to the integral in question, taking advantage of the fact that $$\frac{d}{dx}\operatorname{erfi}(x) = \frac{2}{\sqrt{\pi}}e^{-x^{2}}.$$  We have then $$\int_0^1 e^{-x^2}\,dx = \frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{2}\left(\operatorname{erfi}(1) - \operatorname{erfi}(0)\right) = \frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{2}\operatorname{erfi}(1).$$